# Why this line is not executing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am saving a form in ASP.Net and C#. Every thing works fine except the message after save is not displayed. It is getting lost somewhere in between i am not able to figure why?

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fisherId;
        try
        {
            if (ValidateControls())
            {
                _traceLog.AppendLine("Fisheries Registration Form saving : btnSave_Click() ");
                FillDemographicsObjects();

                if(_manager.CreateFisherDemographics(_demographics, _address, "Test User",out fisherId))
                {
                   /*ShowMessage(IntertribalFishriesResource.msgSaveSuccess);*/

                    if (_shared.SendMailToFisher(fisherId))
                    {
                        _traceLog.AppendLine("Fisheries Registration Form ending : btnSave_Click() ");
                        Response.Redirect("~/Fisher/FisherRegistration.aspx?Id=" + fisherId, false);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _userException.CreateExceptionLog(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _userException.CreateTraceLog(_traceLog.ToString());

        }

    }
```

Message displayed in greyed text is not executed. ShowMessage is given below:

```
  protected bool ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        if (message.Length > 0)
        {
            hidErrMsg.Value = message;
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upFisherRegistration, this.GetType(), "myScript", "ShowMessage();",true);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What I want to achieve is that , after successful save operation , i want to display message and redirect the page. Thats all.

Comment: Is the email being sent?

Comment: everything works except the alert message. Even i put only alert under script manager , it wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI,

when you add RegsiterStartupScript this will be executed for current Request session and it will be written to response, if you redirect after it than your message wont be shown because script doesn't exists in response.

What you need to do is add another parameter in redirect url like &showSaveMessage=true
and on redirected page check if showSavemessage is true add Register startup script method.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The message is sent to a client script on the page that is currently loading.  If the next clause is true, the Redirect will cause another page to load.  So whatever was emitted to the current page would be moot.

Comment: The page you're redirecting to will have to be aware of the need for the message.  I have done this in the past by including an indicator in a query parameter, but there are many ways to accomplish it.